# Adding assembler output to a CMake project

Tags: assembly, cmake, ninja

I'm looking into the ReactOS source code, and I would like to see the assembler output of the compiler. So I have to set the `-s` option to the build system. Another problem is, that this would mean that the compiler must be called a second time, one for building the assembler file and the other to build the regular `.o`  file. 
The build system for ReactOS is `ninja`, is this even possible? Alternatively I could create a separate build directory for the assembly files only, but I still don't see how I can pass the option to the compiler.

Comment: Use `-save-temps` instead. That way you only need a single pass.

Comment: Will this option generate the assembly output? Or do I have to use `-S -save-temps` to create both files?

Comment: Just `-save-temps` (assuming you are using `gcc`).

Comment: @Jester, if you create an answer I would gladly accept it, as this is exactly what I was looking for. :) In order to create the file in the same object path I had to use `-save-temps=obj`.